# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[ContactEntity]>.Element' (aka 'Binding<ContactEntity>') to expected argument type 'ContactEntity'

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data, swiftui

Using Xcode 13.4.1 on macOS 12.5.  I revised the working code to conform to **MVVM**. This was successful for the first `Entity` (all properties `Optional`) for all CRUD operations.

Using this code as a base, I tackled the second `Entity` (one `Bool` property NOT `Optional`), but it throws the compiler error inside the `ForEach` loop, against 'contact'.  This code was error-free before the **MVVM** conversion.  I've been at this for 4 days and am reaching out, but clearly my limited knowledge is inadequate.

`ContactListView` code below, supported by the `ContactViewModel`, which in turn relies on the `CoreDataManager` code.

```
import SwiftUI
    import CoreData
    
    //class FirstNameSort: ObservableObject {
    //    @Published var firstNameSort: Bool = false
    //}
    
    struct ContactsListView: View {
        // MARK: - PROPERTIES
        
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
        @ObservedObject var contactVM = ContactViewModel()
        @State private var totalContacts: Int = 0
        @State private var search: String = ""
        @State private var searchByChampions = false
        @State var searchByFirstNames = false
        @State private var totalChampions = 0
        
        // MARK: - BODY
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
    //                HStack {
    //                    Toggle("Display Champions only", isOn: $searchByChampions)
    //                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
    //                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    //                        .padding()
    //                    Toggle("Sort by First Names", isOn: $contactVM.sortFirstName)
    //                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
    //                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    //                        .padding()
                    //}
                    List {
                        HStack {
                            Text(searchByChampions ? "Total Champions" : "Total Contacts")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(searchByChampions ? totalChampions : totalContacts)")
                                .bold()
                        }.foregroundColor(.green)
                            .padding()
                        ForEach($contactVM.listofContacts) { contact in
                            NavigationLink(destination:
                                            ModifyContactView(contact: ***contact***)
                                .id(UUID()), label: {
                                ContactRowView(contact: ***contact***)
                                    .id(UUID())
                            })
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: contactVM.deleteContact)
                    }.navigationTitle("Contacts")
                        .toolbar {
    #if os(iOS)
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                EditButton()
                            }
    #endif
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                NavigationLink(destination: AddContactView(), label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            countContacts()
                            countChampions()
                        }
                        .searchable(text: $search, prompt: Text("Contact Last Name?"))
    //                    .onChange(of: search) { value in
    //                        if !value.isEmpty {
    //                            listofContacts.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "contactLastName CONTAINS[dc] %@", value)
    //                        } else {
    //                            listofContacts.nsPredicate = nil
    //                        }
    //                    }
                }
            }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
        
        func countContacts() {
            totalContacts = $contactVM.listofContacts.count
        }
        
    //    func countChampions() {
    //        totalChampions = $contactVM.listOfChampions.count
    //    }
    }
```

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

class ContactViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var dataVM = CoreDataManager()
    @ObservedObject var qualifierVM = QualifierViewModel()

    @Published var inputFirstName: String = ""
    @Published var inputLastName: String = ""
    @Published var inputCellNumber: String = ""
    @Published var inputEmail: String = ""
    @Published var inputChampion: Bool = false
    @Published var inputComments: String = ""
    @Published var inputCreated: Date = Date()
    @Published var inputUpdated: Date = Date()
    @Published var listOfFirstNames = []
    @Published var listofContacts: [ContactEntity] = []
    
    func fetchContacts() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ContactEntity>(entityName: "ContactEntity")
        
        do {
            dataVM.listofContacts = try dataVM.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addContact(
        contactFirstName: String,
                          contactLastName: String,
                          contactCellNumber: String,
                          contactEmail: String,
                          contactChampion: Bool,
                          contactComments: String,
                          contactCreated: Date,
                          contactUpdated: Date) {
                              let newContact = ContactEntity(context: dataVM.container.viewContext)
                          newContact.contactFirstName = contactFirstName
                          newContact.contactLastName = contactLastName
                          newContact.contactCellNumber = contactCellNumber
                          newContact.contactEmail = contactEmail
                          newContact.contactChampion = contactChampion
                          newContact.contactComments = contactComments
                          newContact.contactUpdated = Date()
                          newContact.contactCreated = Date()
                              let uniqueClient = Set(dataVM.selectedClient)
                          for client in uniqueClient {
                          newContact.addToClients(client)
                              print("Client: \(client.clientName ?? "No client")")
                          }
        saveContact()
        dismiss()
    }
    
    func deleteContact(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        guard let index = indexSet.first else { return }
        let entity = dataVM.listofContacts[index]
        dataVM.container.viewContext.delete(entity)
        saveContact()
    }
    
    func saveContact() {
        do {
            try dataVM.container.viewContext.save()
            fetchContacts()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving. \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func sortLastName() -> [ Array<Any>] {
        let listOfLastNames = dataVM.listofContacts.sorted {
            $0.contactLastName ?? "" < $1.contactLastName ?? ""
        }
        return [listOfLastNames]
    }
    
    func sortFirstName() -> [ Array<Any>] {
        let listOfFirstNames = dataVM.listofContacts.sorted {
            $0.contactFirstName ?? "" < $1.contactFirstName ?? ""
        }
        return [listOfFirstNames]
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var listOfQualifiers: [QQEntity] = []
    @Published var listofContacts: [ContactEntity] = []
    @Published var listOfClients: [ClientEntity] = []
    @Published var listOfOpportunities: [OpportunityEntity] = []
    //@Published var selectedClient: [ClientEntity] = []
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "B2BContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Successfully loaded Core Data...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `ForEach(contactVM.listofContacts)` instead, that is without the $

Comment: @Joakim - removing $ seems to have done the trick - most grateful.